# Can i manage employee related data in one table?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net, database-design

I have seen people using ‘DataListValue’ table for storing those values (Call_Types, DepartmentCodes, Divisions and etc)  which are used quite often in the drop down list on UI.

This way i can manage them in one table and will have one screen to update codes.

I am wondering if it is okay to keep DepartmentCode,RoleCode,CountryCode in the Data_List Table? Or I should have them in separate table?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is common practice to have a single codes table that stores code/description pairs with some kind of table type column.  For instance, you might commonly see a table like this:

**CodesTable**

- TableId
- Code
- Description

However, I have never thought it was a good idea.  Even if all you store is a code and a description, it's better to make a new table for each set of codes.  That way your foreign key relationships will be more clear.  Plus, inevitably, you will one day need to store some additional data about one of those code sets and you'll end up needing to add an additional column that only applies to one of the code sets that are stored in the table and the column will be null for all the other rows.  It always turns ugly fast.

For instance, lets say, as in the example above, you set `TableId` to "C" for all the Country codes and you set it to "D" for all Department codes.  But then next month a new requirement comes in that requires you to store a postal abbreviation for each Country code.  Do you add a PostalAbbreviation column to the table even though it will never apply to Department codes?  Or do you create another table that just stores additional data for each country code?  How do you know what "C" and "D" mean unless you have some other place to look them up?  All around it's just a bad idea.

Comment: Child table can have three addtinal columns which are Number, Text_1, Text_2, Date_1, Date_2. For an example Date column will be used for cut off dates and number column can be used for types of working hours and text column can be used for PostalAbbrevation.

Comment: Yes, and by following that approach, you could figure out a way to put all the tables of an entire database into one table.  Anything's possible.  The question is, though, why would you want to?  Why make things more difficult and convoluted unless necessary?  What are you gaining and is it worth the cost?

Comment: I am developing timsheet database and as per requiredment employee history needs to be kept, field like Country code,deptCode,Job title and Rolecode will be part of history table (slow dimension change) and this history table will have start and end date as well. I am just thinking whether to have seperate tables for RoleCode, CountryCode and DeptCode and then link them to history table OR have them in one List table and link to History table....